# Access belongs_to data in each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

None of related questions allowed be to resolve this issue so I'm trying a new one.

I have a House model like so:

```
class House < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user, touch: true
    belongs_to :rental
end
```

I have a rental model :

```
class Rental < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :house, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user
end
```

A user can create houses and rentals. When creating rentals, the user can select (with a `<%= f.select ..... %>`) a house he previously added to his dashboard.

Here the form for creating a rental :

```
<%= form_for @rental, url: {action: "create"}, class: "card card--light p-4" do |f| %>
            <div class="field-row flex flex-row align-center justify-center">
                <div class="field m-5">
                    <%= f.label :title, "Name your rental" %>
                    <%= f.text_field :title, class: "input" %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field-row flex flex-row align-center justify-center">
                <div class="field m-5">
                    <%= f.label :house_id, "Select a house" %>
                    <%= f.select :house_id, options_for_select(@houses.map { |h| [h.address, h.id] }), prompt: 'Select', class: 'input' %>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="actions m-5">
              <%= f.submit "Register my rental", class: "btn btn--primary btn-devise" %>
            </div>
        <% end %>
```

I also have a house controller:

```
class HousesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    layout 'dashboard'

    def index
        @houses = current_user.houses
    end

    def show
        @houses = current_user.houses
        @house = House.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @houses = current_user.houses
        @house = House.new
    end

    def create
        @house = House.new(house_params)
        @house.user = current_user

        if @house.save
            redirect_to houses_path
        else
            redirect_to new_house_url
        end
    end

.....
end
```

and a rentals controller:

```
class RentalsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    layout 'dashboard'

  def index
    @houses = current_user.houses
    @rentals = current_user.rentals # i have tried @rentals = current_user.rentals.includes(:house) but doesn't work
  end

  def show
    @rental = Rental.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @houses = current_user.houses
    @rental = Rental.new
  end

  def create
    @rental = Rental.new(rental_params)
    @rental.user = current_user

    if @rental.save
        redirect_to rentals_path
    else
        redirect_to new_rental_url
    end
  end

.........

end
```

Finally, i'm trying to access House data through Rental in my view in an each loop like so :

```
<% @rentals.in_groups_of(3, false) do |rental_array| %>
   <% rental_array.each do |rent| %>
    <%= rent.house.address %>
        <%= link_to 'Edit my rental', edit_rental_path(rent) %>
        .....
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

It gives me this error message: `undefined method`address' for nil:NilClass`.

Here is what i do in the rails console:

```
rental = Rental.last
Rental Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "rentals".* FROM "rentals" ORDER BY "rentals"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
 => #<Rental id: 8, house_id: 15, user_id: 1, created_at: "2019-06-12 09:24:52", updated_at: "2019-06-12 09:24:52", title: "My rental"> 

rental.bien
 House Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "houses".* FROM "houses" WHERE "houses"."rental_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["rental_id", 8], ["LIMIT", 1]]
 => nil
```

I'm confused because i would think that the issue is coming from the form (the `select`) which is not really selecting any house. But on the other hand, we can see in the console that the rental has the right `house_id`. So it seems to actually selecting a house.

Comment: Your `Rental` model seems to have a `house_id` attribute, but you're defining the `Rental` `has_one :house`. This should have been `Rental` `belongs_to :house` instead. The trick to `has_one` vs `belongs_to`, is wherever the `house_id` (or `some_model_id`) attribute is added, that's where you define `belongs_to`, and the other model would be then the `has_one`. In this case you defined the foreign key attribute `house_id` in the `Rental` model, then `Rental` model should `belongs_to :house`, then `House` `has_one :rental`

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario thanks it's working :) you should post it as an answer so i can accept it :)

Comment: Great that it worked! Alright will do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Rental model seems to have a `house_id` attribute, but you're defining the `Rental` `has_one :house`. This should have been `Rental` `belongs_to :house` instead.

The trick to `has_one` vs `belongs_to`, is wherever the `house_id` (or `some_model_id`) attribute is added, that's where you define `belongs_to`, and the other model would be then the `has_one`. In this case you defined the foreign key attribute `house_id` in the `Rental` model, then `Rental` model should `belongs_to :house`, and then `House` `has_one :rental`

Answer (score 1):

The way you want to access attributes is way ok, but:

```
rent.house.address
```

will try first access `house` attribute of `rent` object and if rent has no houses it will return `nil` and after that it will try to access address of... `nil` so thats an error.
try to avoid that type of calling but if no option read about that:
http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/

and in that case:

```
rent&.house&.address
```

should works